# Angular Reactive Forms: Save data in a model on form submit

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I am working on angular reactive form. I fill initial values in the form using a model say `context`, something like this

```
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
    name: [this.context.name],
    age: [this.context.age],
    place: [this.context.place],
    school: [this.context.school]
  });
```

I want to store data back to `context` model on form submit. I am doing it something like this. Is there any elegant way to do that.

```
this.context.name = this.form.value.name;
this.context.age= this.form.value.age;
this.context.place= this.form.value.place;
this.context.school= this.form.value.school;
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use below code and it will assign all your form values to your object back.

`this.context= Object.assign(this.context, this.form.value);`

Answer (score -1):

could be like:

```
this.form.getRawValue().name
```

or even if your form is matching your Context interface it could be something like:

```
 const context = this.form.getRawValue() as Context;
```